# HTML table in php foreach loop where the cell data is only populated if an element is equal to the table column head name

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, html-table

I have created my column headers in my table by using:

```
if (count($round) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<?php foreach ($round as $colhead): array_map('htmlentities', $colhead); ?>
      <th><?php  echo implode('</th><th>',$colhead); ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; endif;
?>
  </thead>
```

`$round` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [32] => -7
            [31] => -6
            [29] => -5
            [27] => -4
            [23] => -3
            [19] => -2
            [17] => -1
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [10] => 3
            [14] => 4
            [16] => 5
            [33] => 6
        )

)
```

This results in exactly what I want because `$round` won't always result in the same number of columns.

The data I want in the table row beneath those headers needs to be only those items that contain the column header's name.

Let's say the column headers are:
**|  -7  |  -6  |  -5  |  -4  |  -3  |  -2  |  -1  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |**
based on the `foreach` loop above.

I used the following to then populate my first column in the next row:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
  <?php foreach ($matches as $match)  {
$firstCharacter = $match['match']['scores_csv'][0];
$lastCharacter = $match['match']['scores_csv'][-1]; 
$id1 = $match['match']['player1_id'];
$id2 = $match['match']['player2_id'];
    if ($match['match']['round'] === -7) 
      echo  "Table: ".$match['match']['player1_votes']."</br>".$participants[$id1]["name"].$participants[$id1]['misc'].": ".$firstCharacter. "</br>".$participants[$id2]["name"].$participants[$id2]['misc'].":".$lastCharacter. "</br>";
  }
  ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And while it works, it's only because I know the header of my first column in the table is -7.  I'm trying to figure out how to only display those items that are equal to my column header to display in the following row based on the column header so that I can then do another foreach loop to display the remainder of my table.  So basically, instead of -7 that I have above, what do I need to do?  I'm completely drawing a blank.

$match['match']['round'] is what is equal to the column headers.  And a small sample $matches is below in case that helps.

```
 [{"match":{"id":246811883,"tournament_id":10128202,"state":"complete","player1_id":152239163,"player2_id":152239166,"player1_prereq_match_id":null,"player2_prereq_match_id":null,"player1_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"player2_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"winner_id":152239166,"loser_id":152239163,"started_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.967+02: 00","created_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.692+02: 00","updated_at":"2021-08-07T02: 22: 29.417+02: 00","identifier":"A","has_attachment":false,"round":1,"player1_votes":1,"player2_votes":null,"group_id":null,"attachment_count":null,"scheduled_time":null,"location":null,"underway_at":"2021-08-07T02: 05: 31.834+02: 00","optional":false,"rushb_id":null,"completed_at":"2021-08-07T02: 22: 29.455+02: 00","suggested_play_order":null,"forfeited":null,"open_graph_image_file_name":null,"open_graph_image_content_type":null,"open_graph_image_file_size":null,"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"","scores_csv":"0-2"}},{"match":{"id":246811884,"tournament_id":10128202,"state":"complete","player1_id":152239594,"player2_id":152239168,"player1_prereq_match_id":null,"player2_prereq_match_id":null,"player1_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"player2_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"winner_id":152239594,"loser_id":152239168,"started_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.984+02: 00","created_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.698+02: 00","updated_at":"2021-08-07T02: 32: 30.655+02: 00","identifier":"B","has_attachment":false,"round":1,"player1_votes":2,"player2_votes":null,"group_id":null,"attachment_count":null,"scheduled_time":null,"location":null,"underway_at":"2021-08-07T02: 05: 23.667+02: 00","optional":false,"rushb_id":null,"completed_at":"2021-08-07T02: 32: 30.690+02: 00","suggested_play_order":null,"forfeited":null,"open_graph_image_file_name":null,"open_graph_image_content_type":null,"open_graph_image_file_size":null,"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"","scores_csv":"2-1"}}]
```

I've attempted to reindex the array by using:

```
$matchesa = array_column($matches, 'match');
$matchesa = array_column($matchesa, null, 'round');

foreach ( $matches as $match )  {
            $id1 = $match['match']['round'];
 {
        echo $matchesa[$id1]['round'].PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
```

Desired output is like this:
[image]

Comment: you need to reconstruct `$matches` array based on `$round` array. use `$round` values as keys and get data from `$matches`. make it a new array. Which will give you only data of `$round` values and then no comparison needed. just directly go for foreach

Comment: Also if you have control over fetching data from database (through which `$matches` are made), then you can do indexing there only.it will make thing more simple.

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh I have attempted to index $matches, but now I'm stuck there.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: can you give us your matches by using json_encode($matches) instead of var_dump or print_r

Comment: I've made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store all the matches based on the rounds:

```
<?php

/*#########SAMPLE DATA########*/

$matches = <<<MATCHES
[{"match":{"id":246811883,"tournament_id":10128202,"state":"complete","player1_id":152239163,"player2_id":152239166,"player1_prereq_match_id":null,"player2_prereq_match_id":null,"player1_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"player2_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"winner_id":152239166,"loser_id":152239163,"started_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.967+02: 00","created_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.692+02: 00","updated_at":"2021-08-07T02: 22: 29.417+02: 00","identifier":"A","has_attachment":false,"round":1,"player1_votes":1,"player2_votes":null,"group_id":null,"attachment_count":null,"scheduled_time":null,"location":null,"underway_at":"2021-08-07T02: 05: 31.834+02: 00","optional":false,"rushb_id":null,"completed_at":"2021-08-07T02: 22: 29.455+02: 00","suggested_play_order":null,"forfeited":null,"open_graph_image_file_name":null,"open_graph_image_content_type":null,"open_graph_image_file_size":null,"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"","scores_csv":"0-2"}},{"match":{"id":246811884,"tournament_id":10128202,"state":"complete","player1_id":152239594,"player2_id":152239168,"player1_prereq_match_id":null,"player2_prereq_match_id":null,"player1_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"player2_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"winner_id":152239594,"loser_id":152239168,"started_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.984+02: 00","created_at":"2021-08-07T01: 59: 51.698+02: 00","updated_at":"2021-08-07T02: 32: 30.655+02: 00","identifier":"B","has_attachment":false,"round":1,"player1_votes":2,"player2_votes":null,"group_id":null,"attachment_count":null,"scheduled_time":null,"location":null,"underway_at":"2021-08-07T02: 05: 23.667+02: 00","optional":false,"rushb_id":null,"completed_at":"2021-08-07T02: 32: 30.690+02: 00","suggested_play_order":null,"forfeited":null,"open_graph_image_file_name":null,"open_graph_image_content_type":null,"open_graph_image_file_size":null,"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"","scores_csv":"2-1"}}]
MATCHES;

$round = <<<ROUND
[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ROUND;

$matches = json_decode($matches, true);
$round = json_decode($round);


/*###########################*/

//class to define data when we found a match
class MatchInfo {
    public $firstCharacter;
    public $lastCharacter;
    public $player1Votes;
    public $player1Name;
    public $player1Misc;
    public $player2Name;
    public $player2Misc;
}

$tableHeaders = null;
$matchInfoData = [];
//$participants = [...]

if (!empty($round)) { //if we have round
    //get the html for table headers
    $tableHeaders = array_map(function($colHead){
        return "<th>Round: {$colHead}</th>";
    }, $round);
    $tableHeaders = implode("", $tableHeaders);

    //remove item in matches
    while ($match = array_pop($matches)) {
        $targetRound = $match['match']['round'];
        if (!in_array($targetRound, $round)) continue; //skip item if match round is not in our column

        if (!array_key_exists($targetRound, $matchInfoData)) { //if we never look at this round before
            $matchInfoData[$targetRound] = []; //initialize array to hold other match based on the round
        }


        $id1 = $match['match']['player1_id'];
        $id2 = $match['match']['player2_id'];
        //new up and save off the data
        $matchInfo = new MatchInfo();
        $matchInfo->firstCharacter = $match['match']['scores_csv'][0];
        $matchInfo->lastCharacter = $match['match']['scores_csv'][-1];
        $matchInfo->player1Votes = $match['match']['player1_votes'];
        $matchInfo->player1Name = "Player1 Name"; //$participants[$id1]["name"];
        $matchInfo->player1Misc = "Player1 Misc"; //$participants[$id1]["misc"];
        $matchInfo->player2Name = "Player2 Name"; //$participants[$id2]["name"];
        $matchInfo->player2Misc = "Player2 Misc"; // $participants[$id2]["misc"];

        $matchInfoData[$targetRound][] = $matchInfo; //add data to the round...array_push
    }

}

//if no matches found exit
if (empty($matchInfoData)) {
    echo "No match info";
    exit;
}

$tableData = '';
//now we loop through all the array to be sure its the same order as the ths
foreach ($round as $td) {
    $columnHtml = '';
    if (array_key_exists($td, $matchInfoData)) { //if what we stored contains the targeted column
        //create a td html
        $dataHtmlArray = array_map(function(MatchInfo $curItem){
            return <<<ITEMDATA
    <div class="match-info">
        Table: {$curItem->player1Votes} <br/>
        {$curItem->player1Name} {$curItem->player1Misc} {$curItem->firstCharacter} <br/>
        {$curItem->player2Name} {$curItem->player2Misc} {$curItem->lastCharacter } <br/>
    </div>
ITEMDATA;

        },$matchInfoData[$td]);

        $dataHtml = implode("<br/>", $dataHtmlArray);
        $columnHtml = "<td><div class='match-container'> {$dataHtml} </div></td>";

    }else { //otherwise it needs a blank td to go to next column
        $columnHtml = "<td></td>";
    }
    $tableData .= $columnHtml;
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr><?php echo $tableHeaders; ?></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $tableData; ?>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
    .match-info {
        border: 1px solid #dadde5;
        padding: 24px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments up front:

Your `$round` array has one element yet you have a `foreach` statement iterating "all" of the elements ...

```php
foreach ($round as $colhead): array_map('htmlentities', $colhead);
```

... which doesn't make much sense semantically because a table should not have multiple headers. Then you invoke `array_map` on the `$colhead` list but the results are not saved and used later on. Moreover, as these values are integers, there is no reason to even apply the `htmlentities` function to these values. Later on, when you are putting out entities such as names, is where this function could prove useful.

The following code builds a map between a round number and the index into the `$matches` array where that round number can be found. Then the processing becomes greatly simplified. Just for demo purposes:

1. I am only outputting for each match the `player1_id` value so that the details of processing do not get lost and for simplicity sake I have set this value to be the same as the round number.
2. If a matching round is not found, the table column is just filled with a `<br>`.
3. Also for simplicity sake I have defined the `$round` array to contain one element, a list with values `[-1, -3, -5]` and the $matches array will only have data for two table rows. The first row for round numbers -1 and -5 (-3 will be missing) and the second row will have all three round numbers.

```php
<?php
$round = [[-1, -3, -5]];

$match0 = [];
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => 2, 'player1_id' => 2));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => 1, 'player1_id' => 1));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => 3, 'player1_id' => 3));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -1, 'player1_id' => -1));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -4, 'player1_id' => -4));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -5, 'player1_id' => -5));
$match0[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -6, 'player1_id' => -6));

$match1 = [];
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -7, 'player1_id' => -7));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -1, 'player1_id' => -1));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -2, 'player1_id' => -2));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -3, 'player1_id' => -3));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -8, 'player1_id' => -8));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => 9, 'player1_id' => 9));
$match1[] = Array('match' => Array('round' => -5, 'player1_id' => -5));

$matches = [$match0, $match1];


if (count($round) > 0):
    $round0 = $round[0];
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
<?php
    foreach($round0 as $hdr):
?>
      <th><?= $hdr ?></th>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($matches as $match):
        // create mapping between round number and index into $matches:
        $index_map = [];
        $l = count($match);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++):
            $matchRound = $match[$i]['match']['round'];
            $index_map[$matchRound] = $i;
        endfor;
?>
    <tr>
<?php
        foreach($round0 as $matchRound):
            if (!array_key_exists($matchRound, $index_map)):
?>
      <th><br></th>
<?php
            else:
                $theMatch = $match[$index_map[$matchRound]]['match']
?>
      <th><?= $theMatch['player1_id'] ?></th>
<?php
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Outputs:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>-1</th>
      <th>-3</th>
      <th>-5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>-1</th>
      <th><br></th>
      <th>-5</th>
    <tr>
      <th>-1</th>
      <th>-3</th>
      <th>-5</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This only produces the first match, there are multiple matches per round.  Desired output is all matches that have a the same round number within the row beneath the column headers.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already have all your header columns in `$colhead`.

So, you can iterate the columns, like this:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $colindex = 0;
    for ($colindex = 0; $colindex < count($colhead), $colindex++) {
        if ($match['match']['round'] === $colhead[$colindex]) {
            //your cell template here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking to all matches in the same row based on column header matching.

Comment: @JenniferHamilton edited my answer. Please let me know if you have difficulties applying this idea.